Is it possible to use a normal map to create the effect of a raised surface that is also flat over a large area (rotatable 3D model)?
Example:
I have a flat surface. On this flat surface, I want a very thin rectangle. It's the same size (W x L) of say a sheet of paper, but not quite as thin (H) as paper (say as thick as a stack of 20 sheets).
Is it possible to do this with a normal map? Or does it require constant changing of "depth" to actually create an effect?
(I'm trying to create a similar effect, except for a very "small" sheet of paper, the size of say a stamp, but I cannot get it to function properly.)
Note: I am using a black and white gradient of sorts in GIMP to create an image which I then use as a stencil in Blender. This part of the process works, as I experimented with linear "indentations" and they function fine (I don't think the issue is with this step within Blender, but in how I'm making the source gradient for the stencil, or perhaps in my expectations/understanding of the technique in general).
EDIT: perhaps the stencil step is what's causing an issue, as within Blender, I have to select Black/White or White/Black, and I can also Invert or not Invert in the nodes section. Is this where the problem lies? Meaning the order of the gradient in GIMP itself (B to W or vice-versa) doesn't matter? In any case, my original question remains.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Blender questions should be asked on Blender Stack Exchange.

This is what displacement modifiers are for

Are you saying I should manipulate the model? I'm very new to this whole thing.
Manipulating the model is not an option by the way.

You can do this with normal map, though a bump may be easier to make (bump map is sort of a normal map precursor, it gets made into normal's). But this question is in the wrong place. Note: there is a difference between the word graphic versus graphics. So for example graphic design deals with conveying messages via visual means, whereas graphics design deals with constructing images. Which is why a site called graphic design can reject a question on image generation. While there is overlap its not really a central graphic design question. BTW. Change to model can be temporary.
